# How to paint an outline when hovering over a QListWidget item?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistwidget, qstyleditemdelegate

I am trying to paint an outline around a QListWidget item when the mouse is over that item. I've subclassed `QStyledItemDelegate` and overrode `paint` to account for the `QStyle::State_MouseOver` case as follows:

```
class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    MyDelegate(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QStyledItemDelegate(parent){}

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
        if(option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver) painter->drawRect(option.rect);
    }

    ~MyDelegate(){}
};
```

I then instantiate a QListWidget with some items and enable the `Qt::WA_Hover` attribute:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QListWidget w;
    w.addItems(QStringList{"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"});
    w.setItemDelegate(new MyDelegate(&w));
    w.viewport()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Unfortunately, the behaviour is not what I expected. In particular, the outline is painted when I move the mouse over an item, but when I move to another item the outline around the first item is not erased. Instead, it keeps drawing outlines around all the items I move my mouse over and eventually there is an outline around all items. Is this normal? I know that an alternative solution would be to use `QStyleSheet`s but I'd like to understand why the current approach doesn't behave as I expected.

Here is what the widget looks like before a mouse over:

[image]

Here it is after hovering over item2:

[image]

And then after item3:

[image]

I am using Qt 5.15.1 on a MacOS 10.15.6 platform.

**EDIT 1:**

Based on the answer from scopchanov, to ensure the outline thickness is indeed 1px, I've changed the `paint` method to this:

```
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
{
    int outlineWidth = 1;
    QPen pen;
    pen.setWidth(outlineWidth);
    painter->setPen(pen);

    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    if(option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver) {

        int a = round(0.5*(outlineWidth - 1));
        int b = round(-0.5*outlineWidth);

        painter->drawRect(option.rect.adjusted(a, a, b, b));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the behaviour is very similar; here is a screenshot after hovering over all items from top to bottom:

[image]

Comment: Yes, apologies, I posted a comment to the answer section. Setting outlineWidth=2 indeed works. I still don't understand why doesn't it work with outlineWidth=1 unless I adjust the rectange with (1,1,-1-1) though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause

`QPainter::drawRect` draws a rectangle, that is slightly bigger (by exactly one pixel in height and width) than the painted area. The reason for this behavior could be seen in [the way `QPaintEngine` draws a rectangle](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/painting/qpaintengine.cpp.html#_ZN12QPaintEngine9drawRectsEPK6QRectFi):

```
for (int i=0; i<rectCount; ++i) {
    QRectF rf = rects[i];
    QPointF pts[4] = { QPointF(rf.x(), rf.y()),
                       QPointF(rf.x() + rf.width(), rf.y()),
                       QPointF(rf.x() + rf.width(), rf.y() + rf.height()),
                       QPointF(rf.x(), rf.y() + rf.height()) };
    drawPolygon(pts, 4, ConvexMode);
}
```

`QPaintEngine` draws a closed polygon, starting at the point `(x, y)`, going to `(x + width, y)`, then to `(x + width, y + height)` and finally to `(x, y + height)`. This looks intuitive enough, but let's see what happens, if we substitute these variables with real numbers:

Say, we want to draw a `4x2` px rectangle at `(0, 0)`. `QPaintEngine` would use the following coordinates: `(0, 0)`, `(4, 0)`, `(4, 2)` and `(0, 2)`. Represented as pixels, the drawing would look like this:

[image: Pixel zoomed rectangle]

So, instead of `4x2` px, we end up with a `5x3` px rectangle, i.e. indeed one pixel wider and taller.

You can further prove this by clipping the painter to `option.rect` before calling `drawRect` like this:

```
if (option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver) {
    painter->setClipRect(option.rect);
    painter->drawRect(option.rect);
}
```

The result is clipped bottom and right edges of the outline (the very edges, we have expected to be within the painted area):

[image: Clipped outline]

In any case, the part of the outline, that falls outside of the painted area, is not repainted correctly, hence the unwanted remains of the previous drawings in the form of lines.

### Solution

Reduce the height and the width of the outline, using [`QRect::adjusted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#adjusted).

You might just write

```
painter->drawRect(option.rect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1));
```

However, this would work only for an outline, which is 1px thick and the `devicePixelRatio` is 1, as on a PC. If the border of the outline is thicker than 1px and/or the `devicePixelRatio` is 2, as on a Mac, of course more of the outline will stick out of the painted area, so you should take that into consideration and adjust the rectangle accordingly, e.g.:

```
int effectiveOutlineWidth = m_outineWidth*m_devicePixelRatio;
int tl = round(0.5*(effectiveOutlineWidth - 1));
int br = round(-0.5*effectiveOutlineWidth);

painter->drawRect(option.rect.adjusted(tl, tl, br, br));
```

`m_outineWidth` and `m_devicePixelRatio` are class members, representing the desired outline width, resp. the ratio between physical pixels and device-independent pixels for the paint device. Provided that you have created public setter methods for them, you could set their values like this:

```
auto *delegate = new MyDelegate(&w);

delegate->setOutlineWidth(1);
delegate->setDevicePixelRatio(w.devicePixelRatio());

w.setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

### Example

Here is an example I have written for you to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QListWidget>
#include <QPainter>

class MyDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    int m_outineWidth;
    int m_devicePixelRatio;
public:
    
    MyDelegate(QObject *parent = nullptr) :
        QStyledItemDelegate(parent),
        m_outineWidth(1),
        m_devicePixelRatio(1) {
    }
    
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
               const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
        
        if (option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver) {
            int effectiveOutlineWidth = m_outineWidth*m_devicePixelRatio;
            int tl = round(0.5*(effectiveOutlineWidth - 1));
            int br = round(-0.5*effectiveOutlineWidth);
            
            painter->setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::red), m_outineWidth, Qt::SolidLine,
                                 Qt::SquareCap, Qt::MiterJoin));
            painter->drawRect(option.rect.adjusted(tl, tl, br, br));
        }
    }
    
    void setOutlineWidth(int outineWidth) {
        m_outineWidth = outineWidth;
    }
    
    void setDevicePixelRatio(int devicePixelRatio) {
        m_devicePixelRatio = devicePixelRatio;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QListWidget w;
    auto *delegate = new MyDelegate(&w);
    
    delegate->setOutlineWidth(3);
    delegate->setDevicePixelRatio(w.devicePixelRatio());
    
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate);
    w.addItems(QStringList{"item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"});
    w.viewport()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
    w.show();
    
    return a.exec();
}
```

### Result

The provided example produces the following result for 3px thick outline on Windows:

[image: 3px thick outline]

Comment: What a great and detailed answer. I'll test it in the morning and accept it, thank you

Comment: I just tried it but it still behaves the same way as before. It works though if I change it to `option.rect.adjusted(1,1,-1,-1)` OR just use `painter->setClipRect(option.rect)` without adjusting the rect. I'd love to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: @linuxfever, I am on windows, so I cannot test how it would look on a mac. Please, show the result of using `adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1)` as a picture.

Comment: @linuxfever, I think I know the reason. On the screenshots the border looks 2 px thick. In the example though the default pen is used, which is 1px thick. Of course, if the border is thicker than 1 px, more of the outline will stick out, so you should have that in mind and adjust the rectangle properly. I will update my answer with this info.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, in my example the pen is also 1px thick... Regarding the picture you asked me, it looks exactly the same as the one I've already attached.

Comment: @linuxfever, on the screenshot the outline is 2 px thick. Please try the code after the note with a `outlineWidth = 2`.

Comment: I've edited my post to accommodate for the outline thickness. Even though I am explicitly setting it to 1px, I still observe the same behaviour. Maybe it behaves slightly differently on Windows and Mac? Thank you again for taking the time to help me!

Comment: oh, wait, setting outlineWidth=2 works! I still don't understand why doesn't it work with outlineWidth=1 unless I adjust the rectange with (1,1,-1-1)...

Comment: :) I've just mentioned that in a comment under your question. It might be indeed mac/windows issue. However, to avoid guessing and be sure, please tell me the result of `qDebug() << painter->pen();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223814/discussion-between-scopchanov-and-linuxfever).